# “date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings…”

Tags: php, timezone

Peguei um sistema para dar manutenção, e ao migrar para outro servidor, começou a dar erro em um input com a data atual, ex:.

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>'>
```

Mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> WARNING:  DATE(): IT IS NOT SAFE TO RELY ON THE SYSTEM'S TIMEZONE
>   SETTINGS. YOU ARE *REQUIRED* TO USE THE DATE.TIMEZONE SETTING OR THE
>   DATE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_SET() FUNCTION. IN CASE YOU USED ANY OF THOSE
>   METHODS AND YOU ARE STILL GETTING THIS WARNING, YOU MOST LIKELY
>   MISSPELLED THE TIMEZONE IDENTIFIER. WE SELECTED THE TIMEZONE 'UTC' FOR
>   NOW, BUT PLEASE SET DATE.TIMEZONE TO SELECT YOUR TIMEZONE. IN
>   **/XXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX/PAINEL-MASTER.PHP** ON
>   LINE **458**
> **WARNING**:  DATE(): IT IS NOT SAFE TO
>   RELY ON THE SYSTEM'S TIMEZONE SETTINGS. YOU ARE *REQUIRED* TO USE THE
>   DATE.TIMEZONE SETTING OR THE DATE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_SET() FUNCTION. IN
>   CASE YOU USED ANY OF THOSE METHODS AND YOU ARE STILL GETTING THIS
>   WARNING, YOU MOST LIKELY MISSPELLED THE TIMEZONE IDENTIFIER. WE
>   SELECTED THE TIMEZONE 'UTC' FOR NOW, BUT PLEASE SET DATE.TIMEZONE TO
>   SELECT YOUR TIMEZONE. IN
>   **/XXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX/PAINEL-MASTER.PHP** ON
>   LINE **458**
> 11/01/2018

Setei no início do PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Mas a partir daí não sei como setar a data (Dia/Mes/Ano) dentro do input, li sobre o que é sugerido no WARNING porém não resolvi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa `timezone` não existe. O Correto é:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Você também pode obter a lista de `timezones` com a função [DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)

Comment: Mas e setando isso, como exibo no input a data ?

Comment: resolvido, ok...

Answer (score 6):

Você provavelmente precisa colocar o fuso horário em uma linha de configuração em seu `php.ini`. Você deve ter algo como isto em seu arquivo `php.ini`:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo
```

Comment: Mas e setando isso, como exibo no input a data ?

Comment: resolvido, ok, graças...

Comment: Acredito ser uma boa solução a nível global do servidor.
Caso tenha programas que necessite mudar o fuso por rodar em alguma região específica, você pode setar no PHP via `date_default_timezone_set()`

Answer (score -4):

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
Isso mesmo, deu certo para mim, vlw pessoal!